# XML Analyzer (not editor!)

Tags: data-visualization, xml, data-analysis

I'm currently working with XML files ranging from a couple of KB's up to MB's for an assignment (7 in total), containing a set of records ranging from 10 records up to 52000.

What I need from a program, is one that can tell me what values a certain variable has.

For example, we have a

```
<recordset>
<record id="id0">
<position>
<x>0</x>
<y>1</y>
<z>2</z>
</position>
</record>
</recordset>
```

What I want it to tell me, is for example, all distinct values any set has for X, e.g. X {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} etc.

I already found a [question for the same problem from several years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/148245/software-for-viewing-and-analyze-big-xml-files), but the answers there don't advertise to do what I want them (mostly fancy editors and formatters).

I am looking for a recommendation for Windows, but I also have an Ubuntu VM so that'll do as well.

Thanks in advance!